# Loadlibrary fails with insufficent buffer while rebuilding pe import table

Tags: c++, c, windows, assembly

I am trying to rebuild the import table of a windows pe now i have successfully enumerated through all the modules but as soon as i use loadlibrary api the application crashes could anyone point me where i am wrong??

```
DWORD OEP, IAT, ImageBase, LoadLib;
char *module;

// Fetch Placeholders
__asm {
    mov[OEP], 0xCCCCCCCC                      // Orignal Entry Point
        mov[IAT], 0xCCCCCCCC                  // Import Table Address
        mov[ImageBase], 0xCCCCCCCC           // Image Base
        mov[LoadLib], 0xCCCCCCCC             // kernel32.LoadLibraryA
}

// Fix IAT
__asm {
_it_fixup:
    mov ebx, [IAT]
        mov esi, [ImageBase]
        add ebx, esi                                    // image_import_descriptor

_it_loadlibrary_loop :
    mov eax, [ebx + 0x0C]                       // eax = image_import_descriptor.Name
        test eax, eax
        jz _it_fixup_end

        add eax, esi                            // ecx = module = image_import_descriptor.Name + dwImageBase

        push eax
        call [LoadLib] // Here when i check with ollydbg eax has advapi32.dll and says error_insufficient_buffer

        inc ebx                             // image_import_descriptor++

        test eax, eax
        jnz _it_loadlibrary_loop

_it_fixup_end :

}

// Jump back
__asm {
    jmp[OEP]
}
```

but when i use

```
 push eax
 mov ecx, [LoadLib]
 call ecx
```

instead of

```
 push eax
 call[LoadLib]
```

the debugger says ecx hold `dvapi32.dll` i am kinda confused please tell me what is wrong here

and yes this `0xCCCCCCCC` is first replace with proper information like kernel32.LoadLibraryA and all

-------------------- EDIT -------------------

updated the codes into c/c++

```
DWORD OEP, IAT, ImageBase, GetProc;
DWORD dwThunk, dwHintName;

typedef HMODULE(WINAPI *_LoadLibrary)(LPCSTR lpFileName);
_LoadLibrary __LoadLibrary;

// Fetch Placeholders
__asm {
    mov[OEP], 0xCCCCCCCC
        mov[IAT], 0xCCCCCCCC
        mov[ImageBase], 0xCCCCCCCC
        mov[__LoadLibrary], 0xCCCCCCCC
        mov[GetProc], 0xCCCCCCCC
}

// Fix IAT
PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDos;
PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR pDesc;

pDos = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)ImageBase;
pDesc = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD)ImageBase + IAT);

char *module;

while (pDesc->Name) {

    module = (char *)((DWORD)ImageBase + pDesc->Name);

    __LoadLibrary(module);

    pDesc++;
}


// Jump back
__asm {
    jmp[OEP]
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to write this code in inline assembly.

Comment: it is i am making a packer and the loader has to be made in assembly

Comment: Your example code is not written in assembly, it's written C/C++ with inline assembly statements. There's nothing in your inline assembly that you couldn't do with normal C/C++ code. If C/C++ code won't work in your loader then neither will this inline assembly. In that case, you'll need to rewrite your code in assembly and assemble it with an assembler.

Comment: Yes you are right :p i have updates the codes and again get problem this time it loops just once and breaks on the second module please have a look

Comment: `__LoadLibrary` points to garbage, what did you expect to happen

Comment: yes i did added a handler to receive the output but it still broke

Comment: "The application crashes" is too vague. Please provide more details, like a stack trace at least.

Comment: here is an image of ollydbg it breaks on advapi32.dll when loading the module with loadlibrary http://i.imgur.com/CMq5EFv.png